# When upgrading to React 18, does a MUI 5 / React 17 app with @mui/styled-engine configuration, are bugs introduced?

Tags: material-ui, styled-components, react-18

I have a 'create react app' using React 17 and MUI 5.  I modified the MUI 5 config to use the 'styled-engine' so I can use styled components as per the documentation at mui.com

I haven't yet tried upgrading to React 18, but I've read in general there are issues/bugs that are introduced.

My question is if there are any posts or docs on how to upgrade to React 18 with a MUI 5 installation that uses the styled-components styling engine???

Answer (score 0):

I've also started with the upgrading to react 18 from 16.8 with MUIv4. it's proven problomatic since i have to change MUI as well to v5.

so, far these are the resouces that helped me:

1. https://reactjs.org/blog/2022/03/08/react-18-upgrade-guide.html
2. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#migrating-from-40x-to-500

Good luck